# AlertDialog in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I'm developing an app which has an Action Bar that splits the main activity in fragments.

Right after opening one of these fragments, I want an alert dialog to be displayed. This dialog will have a positive and a negative button that will do some background actions and then display a message in the fragment.

How can I do that? Do I need a DialogFragment?

Comment: Do you want the Dialog to show immediately or by clicking a view?

Comment: Possibly I want it to be displayed immediately, but a button should be fine too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `AlertDialog` for this case. Call this inside `onCreateView()` method:

```
    AlertDialog myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setMessage("My Dialog Message")
            .setPositiveButton("YES",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                }
            }).setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                }
            }).create();
            myAlertDialog.show();
```

Your `AlertDialog` will have two `Buttons` and will show immediately.